# How to navigate cursor to next appropriate place in IDE (eclipse, Intellij ...)

Tags: xml, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, editor

This maybe a vague question.
When using IDE, we usually use auto-complete, i want to know if there is a shortcut to move the cursor to the next appropriate place (depends on PL).
Example a xml file:

> ```
> <bar>
> <foo>abcxyzz "my cursor here"</foo>
> </bar>
> ```
>
> Now i want to quickly move my cursor to next element (instead using mouse or press alot right arrow key.
>
> ```
> <bar>
> <foo>abcxyzz</foo>"i want move to here"
> </bar>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "End" button on Keyboard.It takes the cursor to end of the Line.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to closing/opening bracket feature in IntelliJ could also be useful for this. It works for XML/HTML, Java, etc. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-braces.html) for more details.

The shortcuts are:

- Navigate to opening bracket: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on Windows/Linux)
- Navigate to closing bracket: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on Windows/Linux)